# Minify HTML, but don't touch PHP with Gulp

Tags: javascript, php, html, gulp, minify

### The problem

I have a lot of *.php* files, mostly containing HTML, but also some PHP lines on top (e.g. form trigger code or similar). So they look like

```
<?php
if($someValue){
    //doSth
}
//more content
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
<head>
    <title>My Website</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>
<!-- Content and scripts here -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

---

### The goal

My goal is to **minify** the HTML (and maybe even the inline javascript, but that's just a little extra), without touching the PHP on top.
I'm using Gulp as automated build tool and would like to see a solution using this tool and any extra packages as they are needed.

Comment: Have you considered using [gulp-htmlmin](https://github.com/jonschlinkert/gulp-htmlmin)? Inline JS can be very tricky to minimise, especially if you have PHP tags interspersed in between—the easiest way is to avoid using inline JS, if ever possible.

Comment: @Terry Yes, I've looked into the package already, but I'm not sure if it supports PHP inside of the HTML file. Haven't had the time yet to test it out though. The problem with inline js is, as stated, just a little extra which I could also live without. My main problem is the PHP block at the beginning (or sometimes inbetween the HTML)

Comment: But why? It is the sourcecode, I suppose you want to keep it readable, and minify rather output generated by your app, not it's code. Are you trying to obfuscate it?

Comment: @michaJlS I want to minify the HTML to decrease the size of the file and improve the loading time of the page.

Comment: If you have PHP code in your templates/whatever, then this code is expected to be interpreted by PHP later, so it should be modified in PHP on-fly or by http server https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module/

Comment: @michaJlS No no, it's all about the HTML. I wan't to minify only HTML, the PHP should be untouched. That's it.

Comment: Yes, I know what you want to do, and it can be done by PHP itself right before serving content to client, or by some module of the HTTP server, and this is the way, how it is often done. Minify on the fly.

Comment: @michaJlS Ah, I got your point! That also sounds like a viable solution though. Will look into this. Anyway, a good solution with Gulp would be interesting too.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The [**gulp-htmlmin**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-htmlmin) module uses the [**html-minifier**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-minifier) module, which has plenty of options (*displayed on both its npmjs.com and github pages*) that can be used. The option we will focus on is `ignoreCustomFragments`.

```
var gulp = require(gulp),
    htmlmin = require(gulp-htmlmin);

gulp.task('htmltask', function(){
  return gulp.src(['./dev/*.html','./dev/*.php'])
      .pipe(htmlmin({
        collapseWhitespace: true,
        ignoreCustomFragments: [ /<%[\s\S]*?%>/, /<\?[=|php]?[\s\S]*?\?>/ ]
      }))
      .pipe(gulp.dest('./site'));
});
```

In the above code, you see we are using `ignoreCustomFragments` with the regex `/<\?[=|php]?[\s\S]*?\?>/` to ignore code starting with `<?` and `<?php` and ending with `?>`.

By default, **html-minifier** ignores php, so you don't have to worry about setting `ignoreCustomFragments`.

**EDIT**
*Thanks amersk*

Some php files you work with may not have closing tags, for example many WordPress files do not. An alternative would be to use the following instead:

`ignoreCustomFragments: [/<\?[\s\S]*?(?:\?>|$)/]`

Comment: I used this for my regex, to allow unclosed php tags at the end of the file

`ignoreCustomFragments: [/<\?[\s\S]*?(?:\?>|$)/]`

Comment: good point. I've noticed gulp errors when not using closing php tags, however, it's common to not have a closing php tag at the end of a file.

Comment: you should update the answer with amersk's suggestion. I'm using this for wordpress and it's littered with unclosed php tags

Comment: This is as complete as it can get: `ignoreCustomFragments: [ /(<[%|\?])([\s\S]*?)(([%|\?]>)|$(?![\r\n]))/ ]`

Comment: [gulp-htmlmin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-htmlmin) seems to be abandoned + `minifyJS` option doesn't work. I'm switching to [gulp-html-minifier-terser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-html-minifier-terser)

Answer (score -1):

This works for me !

```
// Gulp.js configuration
var

  // modules
  gulp = require('gulp'),
  newer = require('gulp-newer'),
  htmlmin = require('gulp-htmlmin')

  // development mode?
  devBuild = (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'),

  // folders
  folder = {
    src: 'src/',
    build: 'build/'
  }

  gulp.task('minify', () => {
     return gulp.src('src/*.html')
     .pipe(htmlmin({ collapseWhitespace: true }))
     .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
  });

;
```